# React call export function in same file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React!

I have a function...

```js
export const getBookingData = () => dispatch => {
  console.log('ran getBookingData');
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

  })
}
```

Which I then call in **another file** by doing (which works fine):

```js
import { getBookingData } from "../actions";
getBookingData(); // logs 'ran getBookingData'
```

However, I would like to try and call `getBookingData` from within the **same file** that it is declared.

I have tried:

```js
const getBookingData = () => dispatch => {
  console.log('ran getBookingData');
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

  })
}

const moveVisitor = (visitorId, destination, source) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  console.log('error with post api'); // logs ok
  getBookingData(); // doesn't log 'ran getBookingData'

  let state = getState();
  let { entities: { booking: { booking_id } } } = state;
  let removeBed = {};
  removeBed.booking_visitor_name_id = visitorId;
  removeBed.room_id = destination;
  removeBed.booking_id = booking_id;

  api.post('/accommodation/room/move-participant', removeBed).then(function (response) {
    // ok
  }).catch(function (error) {

  });
}
export { getBookingData, moveVisitor }
```

Comment: `getBookingData(); // doesn't work` — What does "doesn't work" mean? Is there an error? Some behaviour you don't expect? Provide a *clear problem statement*.

Comment: Just a quick reminder that this `getBookingData` accepts no parameter, which is then returning another function which is accepting `dispatch` as its parameter. You can say that function is curried, so you may need to call it like so: `getBookingData()(yourDispatchObject)`. What you have now by calling `getBookingData()` alone is only returning an anonymous function which of course doesn't do anything if not being called

Comment: @ionizer I think I only partially understand!  If that were the case, then why is it that it works when called in **another file** ?

Comment: This seems to be some `react-redux` stuff which I'm not all too familiar with. But maybe you had mapped your function with `mapDispatchToProps()`?

Comment: Actually, try using `getBookingData()(dispatch)` on where you commented `// doesn't log 'ran getBookingData'`. I think this should work

Comment: @ionizer Yes, that works!! Maybe make this an answer? I still don't understand how it works in the **other file** as `getBookingData()`, but only in the **same file** as `getBookingData()(dispatch)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say that the `getBookingData` function is curried, as it is a function (accepting no parameter) returning another function (accepting dispatch object as parameter). What you have by just calling `getBookingData()` is an anonymous function which accepts the dispatch object as the parameter, so you need to call it once more.

Replacing your non-working call of `getBookingData()` with `getBookingData()(dispatch)` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried exporting as below

```
const getBookingData = () => dispatch => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    // some stuff here
  })
}

const moveVisitor = (visitorId, destination, source) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  getBookingData(); // doesn't work
}

export { getBookingData, moveVisitor }
```

Comment: Although this still works in the **other file** it still doesn't seem to fun when invoked in the moveVisitor function

Comment: @JonathanClark It should work this way, did you double-check to see if you're using it correctly in the same file? You may have missed an argument or something like that ?

Comment: Have updated as maybe the problem wasn't where I thought

Comment: @JonathanClark So `error with post api` is logged, but `ran getBookingData` is not ?

Comment: Try console log before the promise statement, see if it works @JonathanClark

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've updated question to put logs as high as possible